# Discount Rules for WooCommerce not working on the checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, rules, discount

I use Discount Rules for WooCommerce, everything works fine except on the cart page and in the summary despite the settings.

I am using wordpress 5.5.1. Version 2.3.2 and 2.3.7 of the Discount Rules plug-in work everywhere except the checkout page.

Has anyone had a similar problem? Where to look for the cause? I suspect there is something wrong with the versions

Comment: I'll be the first to ask the default support question: "Have you tried disabling all other plugins/theme?"

Comment: Yes, I also tried to use a different theme with only the woocommerce plugin and discount rules. I also tried with the latest version of woocommerce and it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I dont't know about your rule type. Enable this option **Refresh order review in checkout -> Yes** and try it